# How to iterate all static public Guids in static class

Tags: c#, reflection

Given is my sample class:

```
public static class MyConstantClass
{
    public static readonly Guid Prop1 = new Guid("d0f6f396-b75e-4312-bb54-09fbb40cf51e");
    public static readonly Guid Prop2 = new Guid("398810e5-1ed2-468c-9f21-1af58dcecbbf");
}
```

what i have tried so far:

```
var props= typeof(MyConstantClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                 BindingFlags.Static | 
                                                 BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                                  .ToList();
```

But this returns an empty list.

Comment: Those are *fields*, not *properties*, so you will have to use `Type.GetFields(…)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is that these Guids aren't properties but just fields of the class:

```
var props = typeof(MyConstantClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                              BindingFlags.Static |
                                              BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                                   .ToList();
```

To use the `GetProperties` define your class as such:

```
public static class MyConstantClass
{
    public static Guid Prop1 { get; } = new Guid("d0f6f396-b75e-4312-bb54-09fbb40cf51e");
    public static Guid Prop2 { get; } = new Guid("398810e5-1ed2-468c-9f21-1af58dcecbbf");
}
```